# How many BTLE devices can iOS scan while in the background

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am scanning for the presence of many different devices each with a unique service UUID. While my app is in the foreground I can easily discover all devices I am scanning for. However, when I go into the background it seems I can't discover anymore.

When I limit my search to 5 devices I can pick up all five easily. But I haven't found any documentation stating why this is the case. I am aware that backgrounded apps must specify a service to scan for and will not receive duplicate advertisement packets.

Is there a limit to the number of devices or service UUIDs I can scan while in the background? How can I have the same behavior as while in the foreground?